# Are WordPress templates really just HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Are WordPress templates really just HTML styled with CSS in the context of the WordPress "loop"?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at one? What did you see?

Comment: Really?  You earn over 4400 in rep and still don't know how to ask a question here?

Comment: @Sparky672 what did I say that was wrong?

Comment: @JohnConde Yes.  I wanted to know if there was more programming involved.

Comment: Besides the fact that it doesn't make sense... it was something you could easily see for yourself just by looking at a template.  See bullet point #1 here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/157574

Comment: @Sparky672 I thought I met point #1 and the following paragraph.  My question was brief and to the point to know if there were other programming items other than what I had already seen.  "Easily" is in the eye of the beholder.  What is clear to you, may not be clear to me, thus my question.

Comment: When a file starts with `<?php`, I'd say that it's easy to see it contains PHP.  But what does _"in the context of the WordPress 'loop'"_ even mean?

Comment: @Sparky672 if you knew nothing about the WordPress loop, why are you commenting?  It is an integral part of the programming paradigm of WordPress.  Theming is part of that, but the actual presentation layer  may contain more than CSS and HTML.  I do not know for sure, thus, my question.

Comment: Hmmm, lol... I never stated I knew nothing of the Wordpress Loop!  I'm just trying to figure out exactly what you're trying to ask here... based on down-votes, I'm not alone.

Comment: @Sparky672 I somehow doubt you care what I have to ask.  It's clear.  I think it doesn't meet the test of what the SO folks consider a "real" question.  For me it was important, but others obviously could care less.  So be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a Wordpress theme can be as simple as a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) that includes only a single css file with some css overrides, or a full fledged [Theme Framework](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Frameworks) which includes copious amounts of php and more...or they can be just your normal theme(which generally contains css, possibly javascript, and php files that might utilize php only to integrate with the content Wordpress provides into an html document that is embedded in the php file).

The best way to start out playing with themes is to begin making [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) based off a theme like twentyten or twentyeleven made by Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

They are HTML, CSS, <s>Javascript</s>, and **PHP**

Comment: Show me a (regular) page or post template that has js in it. I'll believe it when I see it...

Comment: @JohannesPille your right it doesn't come with any preinstalled JS that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer to your question can be found on the requirements page for Wordpress, http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/ where you see that php and mysql are required. If you browse through the developer and advanced topics sections you will see topics about the use of javascript and ajax in word press. I am sure there are other options available depending on how your installation is set up.